# Can you use turbolinks with webpack in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, turbolinks

This [post](http://pixelatedworks.com/articles/replacing-the-rails-asset-pipeline-with-webpack-and-yarn/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) provides an excellent tutorial on how to replace the rails asset pipeline with webpack. However, it states that  you should remove the turbolinks gem.  Is there a way to do this and still use turbolinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it directly from NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbolinks and follow the provided documentation.

Here is the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbolinks#installation-using-npm

This the same as when you use Turbolinks in other frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to have both, turbolinks from npm and the gem because the `redirect_to` behavior is modified with the ruby code inside of the gem.

If you have disabled Sprockets (e.g using the --skip-sprockets option) you will need to disable the "auto-require" of the gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks', require: false
```

And then you can include Turbolinks::Redirection module in your application_controller.rb:

```
require "turbolinks/redirection"

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Turbolinks::Redirection
  # ...
```

I've sent a Pull Request to  allow the [use Turbolinks without Sprockets](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-rails/pull/18)

Comment: It looks like the pull request was merged in 2018 so maybe this answer needs updating.