# Redirecting with Turbolinks via Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks-5

In a Rails 5.1 app (with Turbolinks enabled), I have the following form

```
  <%= form_with model: @role, url: admin_roles_path, method: :post do |f|  %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= button_tag 'submit, type: 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
```

And the corresponding (dummy) controller

```
class Admin::RolesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @role = Role.new
  end

  def create
    redirect_to admin_roles_path
  end
end
```

Not sure why but the redirect is not working. The controller renders `admin/roles/index.js.erb` instead.

UPDATE
I have installed Turbolinks using webpacker and, from the doc

> The npm package alone does not provide server-side support for
> Turbolinks redirection. See Following Redirects for details on adding
> support.

Which took me here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#following-redirects

How can I send the `Turbolinks-Location` header in the final response from within the Rails controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use turbolinks with webpack in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685627/can-you-use-turbolinks-with-webpack-in-rails)

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember this issue.